# What comes first, window trim or stucco?

Tags: trim

We have some new windows in new construction with only lath around them and some existing windows with existing stucco around them. At what stage would be the best time to install wood window trim?

Comment: Are you asking whether the wood casing goes over or next to the stucco? I don't think I've seen wood trim with stucco. Kinda defeats the purpose of the long-term, low-maintenance nature of stucco. Maybe a photo of the idea would help.

Comment: Interior or exterior? "Wood trim" sounds more like an interior thing while "stucco" sounds like you're talking about exterior surfaces...in general, trim would go on after the wall surface(s)...Are you using plaster/stucco interchangeably? I have trouble picturing exactly what you mean... Pictures are essential I think in this case.

Answer (score 1):

First the window goes in then the stucco on the outside and trim on the inside. We usually leave finish trim for last just in case someone drops a ladder through a window while stucco is being put on (it happens) .